# Add new columns using a pandas Series

Tags: pandas, series

I have a pandas DataFrame and a pandas Series. I want to add new constant columns that have the values of the dataframe. In an example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [2,2,3,2,5]})

In [2]: df1
Out[2]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  2
4  5  5

In [3]: s1 = pd.Series({'c':2, 'd':3})

In [4]: s1
Out[4]: 
c    2
d    3
dtype: int64

In [5]: for key, value in s1.to_dict().items():
            df1[key] = value
```

My ugly loop does what I want. But there must be definitely a better solution using maybe some merge or group operation I guess

```
In [6]: df1
Out[6]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  2  3
1  2  2  2  3
2  3  3  2  3
3  4  2  2  3
4  5  5  2  3
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with unpacking `Series` by `**`:

```
df1 = df1.assign(**s1)
print (df1)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  2  3
1  2  2  2  3
2  3  3  2  3
3  4  2  2  3
4  5  5  2  3
```

`Numpy` solution for new `DataFrame` with [`numpy.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(s1.values, (len(df1),len(s1))), 
                  index=df1.index, 
                  columns=s1.index)

df1 = df1.join(df)
print (df1)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  2  3
1  2  2  2  3
2  3  3  2  3
3  4  2  2  3
4  5  5  2  3
```